# Biblatex: Indent second line of Inproceedings title?

Tags: biblatex, indentation

I customized the numeric style  of biblatex, in order to reduce the `\newblock` commands for entry types of inproceedings. The next step is that long titles of inproceedings, which create a second line, should be indented, so that the second line starts aligned with the start of the title in the first line. The indentation is necessary (I think), because of the "In:" label in the first line.

So on the one hand I need to know the length of the "In:" label and on the other hand want to indent the second and following lines by this length.

Here is what I have:

[image]

And what I want:

[image]

Edit: I forgot to mention, that there are several different labels like "In:". For example "doi:" and "URL:". Furthermore, not all blocks, which have a second line should be indented. Instead only special chosen ones should. Sorry, that I forgot that.

Answer (score 2):

You could modify the definition of the list used by the `bibliography` bibenvironment and use `\widthof` (provided by the [`calc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc) package) to calculate the necessary indentation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[block=par]{biblatex}

\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\longblockindent}
\setlength{\longblockindent}{\widthof{In:~}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\longblockindent}% NEW
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\longblockindent}% NEW
      \setlength{\listparindent}{-\longblockindent}% NEW
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
    adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
    adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu
    libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  editor = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  booktitle = {\sometext},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good start and now I understand the definition of the length in the bibliography environment a little bit more. Your solution indents every block, which have several lines. Another thing, that I did not mention, is that there are also other labels like doi and url. They have a different length. How to handle them separately?

Comment: @user18316 I'm afraid that changing the indentation in the middle of an entry is beyond my abilities.

Comment: The "funny" thing is, that it is the default behavior of the original natbib package. Unfortunately, I don't understand the tex programming language, so that I have no idea how to adapt the behavior of natbib to a custom biblatex style.