# Indent of members of a set in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, lists, indentation

Using a `@set` container (at least something similar but for this question a `@set` should do it) I get the following:

[image]

Since this is a bit hard to read I would like to have this instead:

[image]

Everything I tried with `\hangindent`/`\hangafter`, `\parindent` or `itemize` and friends failed.

Any other possibility?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[doi=false,backend=biber,subentry,sorting=nyt,style=numeric-comp,sortsets=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{fish:drugs,
  mainsubtitle = {Drugs and Society},
  year         = {2006},
  editor       = {{Fish, Jefferson M.}},
  maintitle    = {U.S.~public policy},
  publisher    = {Rowman \& Littlefield Publishers, Inc},
  location     = {Lanham, Maryland},
}
@Set{set:fish:drugs,% related is not inherited...
  entryset     = {fish:drugs:gable:alt,fish:drugs:cleveland:use},
}
@Inbook{fish:drugs:cleveland:use,
  crossref  = {fish:drugs},
  author    = {{Mary M.} Cleveland},
  title     = {Use, 'Abuse', Adverse Health Effects, and Addiction},%<-typo in book
  sorttitle = {09 Use, Abuse, Adverse Health Effects, and Addiction},
}
@Inbook{fish:drugs:gable:alt,
  crossref  = {fish:drugs},
  author    = {{Robert S.} Gable},
  title     = {Acute Toxicity of Drugs vs.~Regulatory Status},
  sorttitle = {07 Acute Toxicity of Drugs versus Regulatory Status},
}
\end{filecontents}

\renewcommand{\entrysetpunct}{\par\nobreak}
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibentrysetcount}{\makebox[1em][l]{\smash{\mknumalph{#1})}}\ignorespaces}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}\parindent=0pt

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Note: [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69940/biblatex-indent-second-line-of-inproceedings-title) might be related...

Comment: This one may also be related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409844/105447. If it is, my experience says it might be tricky...

Comment: After your comments in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459759/35864 I tried to come up with a solution. It is fairly easy to have everything appear in a new line, but the hanging indent proved tricky. Every attempt with `enumerate` failed because of the delayed execution of punctuation commands in the punctuation tracker. I uncovered an undesired behaviour in the `related` punctuation handling, but didn't get anywhere. Maybe `@set` is easier ...

Comment: Because I commented something to the same extend earlier today on [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463294/how-to-force-citeyearpar-to-show-year-letter-instead-of-just-year#comment1165535_463294): The braces in `author = {{Mary M.} Cleveland},` and `author = {{Robert S.} Gable},` should not be necessary. The braces in `editor = {{Fish, Jefferson M.}},` look outright wrong.

Comment: @moewe yep - the double braces around (the) fish have been forgotten to remove after fiddling around with other stuff...

Comment: @moewe If you, by any chance, come up with a sensible approach that is also applicable to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409844/105447, I'm still very interested in an approach less convoluted than the one I've then reached.

Comment: @moewe @gusbrs fiddling around with adding `enumerate` to `abx@macro@begrelatedloop` and `abx@macro@endrelatedloop` with `\csappto` right now - looks promising, 'just' have to remove the last hooked delimiter somehow... (working on the code moewe provided in this answer [https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459759/35864])

Comment: @moewe I definitely do not understand how the punctuation tracker works. Should be something like a) announce what punctuation to use after the next output b) use punctuation when the command in a. has and the one _after_ that _will_ output something... so this value must be saved somewhere. `\midsentence` or `\blx@resetpunct` do not work although at least the first one _should_ reset the punctuation tracker accoding to the manual (p. 256), right? So there must be a way to somehow clear it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that seems to work fairly well so far. This solution uses an `enumerate` list for the set members.

The main issue was not, as I initially thought, the punctuation tracker. It was the fact that the involved list environments (the whole bibliography environment is usually a list as well) did not behave as desired (by me) in the context of all kinds of `biblatex` macros. Mainly because of `\leavevmode`. The following code disables `\leavevmode` where (probably reasonably) safe and removes the effect of one `\leavevmode`, which could not be disabled manually, with `\vspace`. Not pretty, but it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,subentry,sorting=nyt,sortsets=true]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{%
  % don't issue \leavevmode inside here
  \let\blx@leavevmode\relax
  % get rid of the \leavevmode from the beginning of the entry
  % this avoids an empty line before the enumerate
  \vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\itemsep\relax}%
  \begin{enumerate}
  \entryset
    {\ifbool{bbx:subentry}
       {\item[\mknumalph{\thefield{entrysetcount}})]}
       {}}
    {}%
  \finentry
  \end{enumerate}
  %\newunit\newblock
  %\usebibmacro{setpageref}%
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\entrysetpunct}{\finentrypunct}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{fish:drugs,
  mainsubtitle = {Drugs and Society},
  year         = {2006},
  editor       = {Fish, Jefferson M.},
  maintitle    = {U.S.~public policy},
  publisher    = {Rowman \& Littlefield Publishers, Inc},
  location     = {Lanham, Maryland},
}
@Set{set:fish:drugs,% related is not inherited...
  entryset     = {fish:drugs:gable:alt,fish:drugs:cleveland:use},
}
@Inbook{fish:drugs:cleveland:use,
  crossref  = {fish:drugs},
  author    = {Mary M. Cleveland},
  title     = {Use, 'Abuse', Adverse Health Effects, and Addiction},%<-typo in book
  sorttitle = {09 Use, Abuse, Adverse Health Effects, and Addiction},
}
@Inbook{fish:drugs:gable:alt,
  crossref  = {fish:drugs},
  author    = {Robert S. Gable},
  title     = {Acute Toxicity of Drugs vs.~Regulatory Status},
  sorttitle = {07 Acute Toxicity of Drugs versus Regulatory Status},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The screenshot shows a bibliography with two items. The second item is a <code>@set</code> entry and subdivided into a) and b). The layout of that second entry is that of a usual <code>enumerate</code>.]

Comment: That's very nice! If I may suggest, I think some sort of support for nested listing within the bibliography environment would improve output for sets, multivolumes (related too?). In general, anywhere where some sort of grouping is trying to be conveyed.

Comment: @gusbrs thumb up!

Comment: @gusbrs Feel free to open a feature request at GitHub. My attempts to solve this issue have shown me that it is quite tricky to get `biblatex` to print lists inside entries they way one would expect them to print. So I'm not at all hopeful that I'd be able to come up with something. Furthermore, the usual setup and at least the standard bibliography drivers are not really equipped to deal with lists inside entries. So the first question would have to be "what exactly are we looking for", then we need to discuss if and how this can be integrated into the standard styles ...

Comment: ... and then there is the small question of how to implement it.

Comment: Well, mine showed the same. But I see a use case, which is occasional, but real. My attempts are somewhat cold in memory, but I'll go through things again and see what I can come up with and make a request.

Comment: The feature request is now at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/844

Comment: @moewe Thanks for bringing the link to the request here. I missed that. Besides that, would you like to answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409844/105447 with https://gist.github.com/gusbrs/fb6ae4388d82cb34efe83d29bbd09785 ?

Comment: Since you came up with the necessary steps to make it work in that specific situation, why don't you answer yourself?

Comment: @moewe The critical step to achieve it is yours... The credit is due. Unless, of course, you prefer that I answer it.

Comment: @gusbrs Since you have already done all the work to come up with the working MWE that displays the solution I think it is only fair that you would answer it. Plus it is your question, so you know what was asked for in the first place. And a link back to this answer here will be enough credit.

Comment: @moewe I did so as CW. Thank you very much. Two comments on my attempt there, which might interest you. First, I tried to bring the `\blx@leavevmode` and `\vspace` to the list environment to get a cleaner bibdriver, without success. Second, without the option `locallabelwidth=true` it seems the lenght `\shorthandwidth` was not generated (it worked either with the option or if `\printshorthands` was issued in the document, without both the length was lost).

Comment: @gusbrs Yes, the global `shorthandwidth` is only calculated if and when it is needed (i.e. in `\printshorthands`); `locallabelwidth` is not as careful and always produces the length, but it should not matter that much for the local labels. I'm not sure how exactly you tried to integrate `\blx@leavevmode` and `\vspace` into which list environment, but my tests have shown me that the entire thing is quite fragile if the order of executions of certain commands is changed.

Answer (score 3):

Well, finally and after combining this question with [this related problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459759/additional-fields-for-biblatex-biber-set) I found a way to expand `@set` types to produce the desired output. It`s a bit tricky but basically straight forward.

So a `@set` gets the key to the header part via the `options`-field. Within the redefined `setdriver` the header is printed. Since the set does not hold any values the `entryset` command has to be run from within the (re)loaded headerdata:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{%
  \edef\xs@mv@set{\abx@field@entrykey}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifundef{\xs@mv@head}}
    or
    test {\ifblank{\xs@mv@head}}
    }
    {\entryset{}{}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
     \finentry}
    {\entrydata*{\xs@mv@head}{\usedriver{}{\abx@field@entrytype}\finentrypunct%
       % reload the set so we can access the header via saved
       \entrydata*{\xs@mv@set}{
         % don't issue \leavevmode inside here
         \let\blx@leavevmode\relax
         \setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}%
         \begin{itemize}[label={\printfield{entrysetcount})},labelindent=0.5\labelnumberwidth,labelsep=1ex,itemindent=0pt,leftmargin=*]
         \entryset{\item \ifcsdef{blx@bbx@multivolume\abx@field@savedentrytype}
           {\edef\abx@field@entrytype{multivolume\abx@field@savedentrytype}}
           {\message{^^Jxs Warning: BibliographyDriver blx@bbx@multivolume@\abx@field@entrytype\space undefined
                     ^^J** Using fallback driver multivolumechild
                     ^^J** If you get unexpected entries in the bibliography consider to create a new BibliographyDriver multivolume@\abx@field@savedentrytype.}%
            \def\abx@field@entrytype{multivolumechild}}}{}%
         \finentrypunct\end{itemize}\nopunct}}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
     \finentry}}
```

Within the `entryset`-loop the `entrytype` of each child is changed to a new driver printing only what was not provided in the header block. If there is a driver `multivolume<child-entrytype>` this special driver will be used, if not the generic fallback `multivolumechild`-driver kicks in. That allows to mix entrytypes within `@set` constructions.

What you get in the end is:

[image]

Thanx to moewe for all the hints related to this problem (and to all involved in the discussion).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,mcite,subentry,sorting=nty,sortsets=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat{entrysetcount}{\mknumalph{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  editor  = {Hrsg},
  editors = {Hrsg},
  volumes = {B\"ande},
}

\makeatletter
\DeclareEntryOption[string]{multivolumehead}{\def\xs@mv@head{#1}}
\define@key{xs@multivolume}{multivolumehead}{\def\xs@mv@head{#1}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{multivolumechild}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifnamesequal{author}{savedauthor}}
      or
      test {\ifnameundef{author}}
    }
      {\nopunct}
      {\printnames{author}%
       \newunit\newblock}%
    \iffieldundef{volume}
      {}
      {\printfield{volume}%
       \printfield{part}%
       \newunit\newblock}%
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifnamesequal{editor}{savededitor}}
      or
      test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
     }{}
      {\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
       \newunit\newblock}%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\iflistsequal{location}{savedlocation}}
      or
      test {\iflistundef{location}}
     }{}
      {\printlist{location}}%<- typo
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\iflistsequal{publisher}{savedpublisher}}
      or
      test {\iflistundef{publisher}}
    } {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}%
      {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
       \printlist{publisher}%
       \setunit*{\addcomma\space}}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldsequal{year}{savedyear}}
    or
    test {\iffieldundef{year}}
   }{}
    {\printdate%
     \newunit\newblock}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldsequal{isbn}{savedisbn}}
    or
    not togl {bbx:isbn}
   }{}
    {\printfield{isbn}}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  }

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{%
  \edef\xs@mv@set{\abx@field@entrykey}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifundef{\xs@mv@head}}
    or
    test {\ifblank{\xs@mv@head}}
    }
    {\entryset{}{}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
     \finentry}
    {\entrydata*{\xs@mv@head}{\usedriver{}{\abx@field@entrytype}\finentrypunct%
       % reload the set so we can access the header via saved
       \entrydata*{\xs@mv@set}{
         % don't issue \leavevmode inside here
         \let\blx@leavevmode\relax
         \setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}%
         \begin{itemize}[label={\printfield{entrysetcount})},labelindent=0.5\labelnumberwidth,labelsep=1ex,itemindent=0pt,leftmargin=*]
         \entryset{\item \ifcsdef{blx@bbx@multivolume\abx@field@savedentrytype}
           {\edef\abx@field@entrytype{multivolume\abx@field@savedentrytype}}
           {\message{^^Jxs Warning: BibliographyDriver blx@bbx@multivolume@\abx@field@entrytype\space undefined
                     ^^J** Using fallback driver multivolumechild
                     ^^J** If you get unexpected entries in the bibliography consider to create a new BibliographyDriver multivolume@\abx@field@savedentrytype.}%
            \def\abx@field@entrytype{multivolumechild}}}{}%
         \finentrypunct\end{itemize}\nopunct}}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
     \finentry}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\entrysetpunct}{\finentrypunct}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{fish:drugs,
  mainsubtitle = {Drugs and Society},
  year         = {2006},
  editor       = {Jefferson M. Fish},
  maintitle    = {U.S.~public policy},
  publisher    = {Rowman \& Littlefield Publishers, Inc},
  location     = {Lanham, Maryland},
  isbn         = {0-7425-4245-9},
  sortname     = {Jefferson M. Fish},
  sorttitle    = {U.S. public policy Drugs and Society},
  options      = {dataonly},
}
@Set{set:fish:drugs,
  entryset     = {fish:drugs:gable:alt,fish:drugs:cleveland:use,fish:drugs:evans:intro},
  options      = {multivolumehead=fish:drugs},
}
@Inbook{fish:drugs:evans:intro,
  crossref   = {fish:drugs},
  author     = {Richard M. Evans and Stanley Neustadter},
  chapter    = {6},
  title      = {Legalization: An Introduction},
  pages      = {129-148},
  sorttitle  = {06 Legalization: An Introduction},
  options    = {dataonly},
}
@Inbook{fish:drugs:cleveland:use,
  crossref   = {fish:drugs},
  author     = {Mary M. Cleveland},
  chapter    = {9a},
  title      = {Use, 'Abuse', Adverse Health Effects, and Addiction},
  pages      = {197-200},
  sorttitle  = {09 Use, Abuse, Adverse Health Effects, and Addiction},
  options    = {dataonly},
}
@Inbook{fish:drugs:gable:alt,
  crossref   = {fish:drugs},
  author     = {Robert S. Gable},
  chapter    = {7},
  title      = {Acute Toxicity of Drugs versus Regulatory Status},
  pages      = {149-161},
  sorttitle  = {07 Acute Toxicity of Drugs versus Regulatory Status},
}
@article{doody,
  author       = {Terrence Doody},
  title        = {Hemingway's Style and {Jake's} Narration},
  year         = 1974,
  volume       = 4,
  number       = 3,
  pages        = {212-225},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  related      = {matuz:doody},
  relatedstring= {\autocap{e}xcerpt in},
  journal      = {The Journal of Narrative Technique},
  annotation   = {An \texttt{article} entry cited as an excerpt from a
                  \texttt{collection} entry. Note the format of the
                  \texttt{related} and \texttt{relatedstring} fields},
}
@collection{matuz:doody,
  editor       = {Roger Matuz},
  title        = {Contemporary Literary Criticism},
  year         = 1990,
  volume       = 61,
  publisher    = {Gale},
  location     = {Detroit},
  pages        = {204-208},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  annotation   = {A \texttt{collection} entry providing the excerpt information
                  for the \texttt{doody} entry. Note the format of the
                  \texttt{pages} field},
}
@Book{A,
  author      = {René Goscinny and Albert Uderzo},
  maintitle   = {Asterix und Obelix},
  year        = {1959--2018},
  publisher   = {Dargaud},
  location    = {Paris},
  volumes     = {99},
  options     = {dataonly},
}
@Set{set:A,
  entryset    = {A:V1,A:V2,A:V3,A:V4,A:V5,A:V6},
  options     = {multivolumehead=A},
}
@Book{A:V1,
  crossref    = {A},
  title       = {Asterix der Gallier},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 01},
  year        = {1959},
  isbn        = {1234567890123},
  volume      = {1},
}
@Book{A:V2,
  crossref    = {A},
  title       = {Asterix und Kleopatra},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 02},
  year        = {1968},
  isbn        = {2345678901234},
  volume      = {2},
}
@Book{A:V3,
  crossref    = {A},
  title       = {Asterix als Gladiator},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 03},
  year        = {1969},
  isbn        = {3456789012345},
  volume      = {3},
}
@Book{A:V4,
  crossref    = {A},
  title       = {Der Kampf der Häuptlinge},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 04},
  year        = {1969},
  isbn        = {4567890123456},
  volume      = {4},
}
@Book{A:V5,
  crossref    = {A},
  title       = {Die goldene Sichel},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 05},
  year        = {1970},
  isbn        = {5678901234567},
  volume      = {5},
}
@Book{A:V6,
  crossref    = {A},
  title       = {Tour de France},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 06},
  year        = {1970},
  isbn        = {6789012345678},
  volume      = {6},
}
@Book{DHS:base,
  editor    = {{Deutsche Hauptstelle für Suchtfragen e.~V.}},
  sortname  = {{Deutsche Hauptstelle für Suchtfragen}},
  year      = {2017},
  url       = {www.dhs.de},
  urldate   = {2018-04-30},
  maintitle = {Suchtmedizinische Reihe},
  options   = {dataonly},
}
@Book{DHS:nik,
  crossref  = {DHS:base},
  title     = {Tabakabhängigkeit},
  sorttitle = {Deutsche Hauptstelle für Suchtfragen Suchtmedizinische Reihe 01},
  volume    = {1},
  isbn      = {978-3-937587-00-4},
}
@Book{DHS:alk,
  crossref  = {DHS:base},
  title     = {Alkoholabhängigkeit},
  sorttitle = {Deutsche Hauptstelle für Suchtfragen Suchtmedizinische Reihe 02},
  volume    = {2},
  isbn      = {978-3-937587-01-1},
}
@Book{DHS:drogen,
  crossref  = {DHS:base},
  title     = {Drogenabhängigkeit},
  sorttitle = {Deutsche Hauptstelle für Suchtfragen Suchtmedizinische Reihe 04},
  volume    = {4},
  isbn      = {978-3-937587-03-5},
}
@Set{DHS:SMR,
  crossref  = {DHS:base},
  entryset  = {DHS:alk,DHS:nik,DHS:drogen},
  options   = {multivolumehead=DHS:base},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}\parindent=0pt\relax\parskip=2ex\relax
\nocite{*}
\fullcite{fish:drugs}

Cleveland in \cite{set:fish:drugs} says\supercite{fish:drugs:gable:alt} something.\msupercite{fish:drugs:gable:alt,fish:drugs:cleveland:use,fish:drugs:evans:intro}

Be adviced that after heavy stuff like \mcite{DHS:nik,DHS:alk} you should relax\msupercite{set:A} a bit.

\fullcite{fish:drugs:gable:alt}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
\endinput
```